# How to insert a picture into a listbox

Tags: vb6

I want to make a program like this:
[image]

The program for children ,combines two numbers with a combined output show in the form of a number of apples.
I have searched the internet for how to insert a picture inside the ListBox for Visual Basic 6 but i could not find it.
please help me with any thigs..

Comment: you can see this like if the link on the top did not work https://ibb.co/jGobgm

Comment: Use a *ListView* - that will let you set a background image, you cannot do that for a ListBox (without owner drawing it).

Comment: To expand on Alex K's comment: the ListView control emulates the views in Windows Explorer. Your apple will be an icon, and you will use Large Icons format. Then, you can add or remove list items to get different numbers of apples. [Here's](: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443482(v=vs.60).aspx) the doc.